# Is there any extension for NEXT, PREVIOUS articles in a category?

Tags: php, plugins, mediawiki

I would like to have a button for fast browsing. I tried to search it but there are too many extensions so I haven't found anything useful. Here is an example

[listed category](http://www.mediawiki.org/w/index.php?title=Special:AllPages&from=%2bsysop&namespace=102) - many items I want to read

[one opened article](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:+sysop)

And when I want to go to the next article, I have to get back and choose it from the list. Can I have `NEXT` and `PREVIOUS` buttons in the opened article with an extension?

Comment: Not that I know of, but it shouldn't be terribly hard to write one.  However, how would you choose which categories to add the links for? For example, the page you linked to belongs to nine categories; while surely possible, it seems kind of awkward to add the next/prev links for all of them.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen My idea is this: I choose a category, click something like `Browse category` button and then all pages would have `NEXT` and `PREVIOUS` buttons for the chosen category.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the [Hierarchy extension](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aHierarchy) has the functionality that you are looking for. It provides several, but I think what you are looking for is called the horizontal method.

Answer (score 1):

I have never seen such an extension.

There is nothing like it in the [Category extensions category](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Category%3aCategory_extensions) at mediawiki.org, which most probably means it doesn't exist or would be hard to find.

It shouldn't be too hard to write, though, so you can give it a try.

If I got the intended usage and placement right the [OutputPageMakeCategoryLinks hooks](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aHooks/OutputPageMakeCategoryLinks) should be the best place to start. Use the `$out` param to add HTML to your page just above the category list.

Good luck.